# Create table with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm creating a table, which will have a date in one of two columns, or neither.

I'd like the third to auto populate with one of these values, without using an update.

```
CREATE TABLE [table1] 
(
    id [BIGINT] NOT NULL,
    [date1] [DATETIME] NULL,
    [date2] [DATETIME] NULL,
    [date] AS (CASE 
                  WHEN [date1] IS NOT NULL THEN [date1]
                  WHEN [date2] IS NOT NULL THEN [date2]
                  ELSE NULL 
               END)
)
```

This doesn't seem to work when I test using:

```
INSERT INTO [table1] (id, date1) 
VALUES (1, GETDATE())
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Your code appears to work fine:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0e9de2f958cbafe08d23db7950044eac.

Comment: Your code works. Tested on SQL2000 and SQL2008R2. The CREATE, the INSERT, and the SELECT to check after.

Comment: This code works fine. Share your testing data and expected result.

Answer (score 3):

Your code appears to be fine, as seen in [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0e9de2f958cbafe08d23db7950044eac) db<>fiddle.  However, I would suggest using `COALESCE()` instead of `CASE`:

```
CREATE TABLE [table1] (
    id [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [date1] [datetime] NULL,
    [date2] [datetime] NULL,
    [date] AS ( COALESCE(date1, date2) )
);
```

It is more concise.

Comment: use of coalesce make this more efficient, in case of n number of columns we don't need to write n cases.